# What is this tree? Tell me please

Tags: identification, trees, planting

[image]

Here is the bark

[image]

I am just curious and really want to find out

Comment: I have confirmed  that this is not a jacaranda

Comment: Claude, welcome! Please check the [tag:identification] [tag info](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info): You can greatly improve your question if you [edit] your post with a few details, e.g. where in the world this tree is growing. It’s also a good idea to take the [tour] and browse through our [help], especially [ask] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: Height and spread estimates would be useful as well as where in the world this tree is, and if you've ever seen it in flower and what they're like, whether there's any thorns and so on...

Comment: @Claude: You need to give us more information, and photos are not so good. Could you make a photo of a single branch (or a single leaves)? Where do you leave? (region/continent is enough). I would bet now for *Albizia julibrissin*, cultivated in Europe

Answer (score 2):

Indian redwood aka sappan wood.  The tree smartly caught your eye because it's a pretty rare find. [image: sketch drawing]